# What is the most up to date Python asterisk AGI framework for asterisk?

Tags: python, frameworks, asterisk, telephony, agi

I have done some AGI development in the past with PERL and PHP, but my current project is using Python.  I have found the frameworks listed here: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI , but they are all pretty old and do not seem kept up to date.  I'd like to know if there are any others out there specifically for asterisk 1.6.2. and preferably written in python 2.6 or higher.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With my Asterisk 1.6.2.7 I use [pyst](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyst/). I haven't changed it for some years (since Asterisk 1.0), and it still works with Python 2.4, but I see that this project lives, has a new maintainer and should work with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Please look into [Pystrix](http://code.google.com/p/pystrix/). I have used Pystrix on Python 2.7 and Asterisk 1.8 without any issue.

Though these libraries are old, but if you see their recent changes, you will find there are just few commits to improve it, its doc and then nothing else. **These library works fine without any issue** in communicating with Asterisk, as Asterisk didn't change the communication pattern with clients from 1.4 to latest (I tested at least 1.8), but they made their commands/applicatiions/functions rich with more arguments. So the existing libraries work fine.

In all these libraries, you will find a method like 'send_action'. All other methods do give you helpers to assemble the commands argument in asterisk recognized format, (ending with \n\r and command ends with \n\r\n\r).